# How can I find the current revision of my project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

I'm using [AnkhSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AnkhSVN) in Visual Studio 2010 and it works perfectly. I want to know the current revision before I update to the latest vision. How can I find the current revision number of my project?

I don't use any other variation of Subversion ([TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN), etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [the revision history](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_view_history.html).

Comment: I'm using the history viewer frequently but i want to know which files of my project will be changed when i press the update button in pending changed pane.

Comment: Sorry: Pending Changes pane of VS2010

Comment: I'm using TFS and git mostly these days, but doesn't it show what files are changed in that window? - http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_view_history.html

Comment: Thx 4 your quick responce.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to stackoverflow and pressed the enter button to quickly. ... but it doesn't show which revision you have in your working directory. i.e. Latest revision on the server is 1433. What is revision in my working directory?

Comment: Each file is going to have it's own revision I believe so you'd have to check the version history on each file individually.